# Matrix plot remove overlapping borders

Tags: pgfplots

When  reduce the opacity of a matrix plot then I find that cells are overlapping. How do I remove this overlap?

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp.dat}
  -1 1 0.5      
  -1 0 1
  -1 -1 1
   0 1 1
   0 0 1
   0 -1 1
   1 1 1
   1 0 1
   1 -1 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      enlargelimits=false,
      axis equal
      ]
      \addplot
      [
        matrix plot*,
        mesh/cols = 3,
        point meta = explicit,
        opacity = 0.5
    ] file { 
    tmp.dat
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit:
Figures of the overlaps
[image]
[image]

I compile using `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex`.

Comment: When I compile your MWE on my updated TeXLive 2019 distribution with pdflatex, there is no evidence that the cells overlap. How do you compile the example? And what precisely do you mean by overlap?

Comment: Does replacing `opacity` by `fill opacity` help?

Comment: No, I still get the borders. Are there no borders when you compile?

Comment: Yes, there are borders. I did not know that this is what you meant by overlaps.

Comment: Is there any command that manipulates these borders? For example, changing the width and color around some cells?

Comment: I have discovered that `faceted color` changes the border color in a surface plot; for example `\addplot3 [ surf, mesh/rows=3, faceted color = none] file {tmp.dat};` However, this fails for `matrix plot`.

Comment: I have discovered that the borders are controlled by the `shader` the default `shader` for `matrix plot*` seems to be `flat corner`, we find the different shaders on page 138 in _Manual for Package PGFPLOTS_, version 1.16. I tried the different options and none of them removes the borders.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the other flat shaders do not remove the borders. `\pgfplotsset{matrix plot*/.append style={shader=interp}}` does but also produces a very different result.

Comment: Worst case, remove [opacity=0.5] and use softer colors instead.

Comment: @John: What do you mean with softer colors?

Comment: The keyword `line width` allows making the lines thinner but the lines remain although I use `\addplot[..., line width = 0pt]`. I am starting to believe that `matrix plot` is the wrong tool for this task.

Comment: These borders seem to be a property of the pgfplots package. I get the same borders if I put two of the following patches next to each other 
```
\addplot3 [ 
patch,
patch type = rectangle,
% faceted color = red,
fill opacity = 0.5,
line width = 0pt
]
´´´
However, using patches I can set the border color as I wish using `faceted color`. Hence, If there is a way to figure out the color of a patch when the opacity is reduced then we can set the borders color to the same color as the interior. How can we find the interior color of a patch with reduced opacity?

Comment: The key `draw opacity` controls the opacity of the borders but setting `draw opacity = 0` fails to remove the borders.

Answer (score 1):

Using softer colors instead of `[opacity=0.5]`:

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp.dat}
  -1 1 0.5      
  -1 0 1
  -1 -1 1
   0 1 1
   0 0 1
   0 -1 1
   1 1 1
   1 0 1
   1 -1 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      enlargelimits=false,
      axis equal,
      colormap={soft}{color=(blue!50!white) color=(yellow!50!white) color=(orange!50!white) color=(red!50!white)}
      ]
      \addplot
      [
        matrix plot*,
        mesh/cols = 3,
        point meta = explicit,
    ] file { 
    tmp.dat
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```